# Node.js server POST requests only go through if there was a GET request before--not sure why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, get, request

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

http.on('request', (request, response) => {

  console.log("the method request was " + request.method) //either prints POST or GET depending on what I'm sending it
  if (request.method == "GET") {
    console.log("GET")
  } else if (request.method == "POST") {
    console.log("POST")
  }

  request.on('error', (err) => {
    // This prints the error message and stack trace to `stderr`.
    console.error("the error was " + err);
  });
  // console.log("got a request to the server")
  response.send("response string")
});

http.listen(port, () => console.log('listening on port ' + port));
```

So basically, the problem is that if I send a GET request, and then a POST request, it prints all the correct stuff. What's weird though is if I just send a POST request first, there are no printouts. If you need to see my client-side Swift code, let me know and I'll add it--thank you!

A video of the issue at hand can be seen here: https://youtu.be/Rac9N9F4KDo

Comment: you are mixing express server with http server.

Comment: @yochanansheinberger I'm using socket.io as well, I just removed the code for that because it kind of detracts from the issue at hand--what exactly do I need to change to make this function correctly?

Comment: how do you listen to your server?

Comment: i tried it via postman and it works fine for me

Comment: @yochanansheinberger http.listen(port, () => console.log('listening on port ' + port)); ---and I can add the client side requests that are being sent out if you want